# How to use global audiences to show a web part A or web part B but not both at the same time?

Tags: sharepoint

I have two web parts:

Web Part A
Web Part B

I have two audiences:

Audience A
Audience B

Audience B needs to contain all users that are NOT members of audience A.

On a web page, I only want to show Web Part A if they are member of Audience A and Web Part B if they are a member of Audience B.  But never both.

I can't get Audience B to show all members that are NOT a member of Audience A.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audience membership can't be defined using logical rules like AND or NOT. It just takes all the members of a SPGroup or AD group and includes them. So, you'd have to be smart about group memberships...

Either make a group that contains all the members you want, to base an audience on or, to go into code, program a nightly timerjob that checks all members against audience A and if they're not in it, adds them to SPGroup B. Then when you're done, have it recompile Audience B, which is based directly on SPGroup B.

Comment: This is what I did, coded a timer job to do just this.  I just wanted to ensure I was not missing something, because this seems like a basic need for the audiencing system in SP.